# Change Column Type of jtable when table populate from resultset

Tags: java, swing, jtable, swingworker, tablemodel

I have worker for fill the jtable from resultset like below;

```
public class WorkerFillTable extends SwingWorker<DefaultTableModel, DefaultTableModel> {
        private DefaultTableModel modeltable;
        public WorkerFillTable(DefaultTableModel modeltable) {
         this.modeltable = modeltable;
        }
       @Override
     protected DefaultTableModel doInBackground() throws Exception {
            ResultSet rs;
            Statement stmt;
            String query = "select Name,ID,Status,IsActive from current_conf\n" +
            "order by Name,ID";

            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.130.100;" + "databaseName=DBST;" + "user=" + "user1" + ";" + "password=" + "userpass1" + ";"; 
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

            Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
            int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

            for (int column = 0; column < columnCount; column++) {
                columnNames.addElement(rsmd.getColumnLabel(column + 1));
            } 

            Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();

           while (rs.next()) {
                Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
                for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
                vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
                }
                data.add(vector);
           }

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            modeltable = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
            return modeltable;
        }


      @Override
      protected void done() {
        try {
            TableModel modeltable = get();
            sorter = new TableRowSorter(modeltable);
            cTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
            cTable.setModel(modeltable);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
        }
      }

    }
```

But all of columns come as String. "IsActive" columns of DB is a bit only have "1" or "0" Jtable shows this columns as "true" or "false" I need edit last column typr to boelan in jtable. How can i do it ?

Comment: EDIT: "IsActive" columns of DB is a bit only have "1" or "0"

Comment: did your read official Oracles tutorials "How to use Tables", Event Dispatch Thread, SwingWorker, never to create Swing JComponents ot its model in worker thread (doInBackground())

Comment: @mKorbel Yes i read them. Above code working succesfully now. Just i want see checkbox in column 4 instead true or false string. I have not problem with swingworker.

Comment: Above code working succesfully now. - not this contruction is wrong, don't do that, forgout about, you have to declare XxxTableModel and publish() a new row to the intialized variable XxxTableModel ouside of SwingWorker, note otherwise you have to add model to JTable

Comment: Yes i read them. then you must toi know that anything inside doInBackground() never notified EDT, for why reason you do that

Comment: I use WorkerFillTable filltable = new WorkerFillTable(modelfilltable);
filltable.execute(); in EDT for fire the jTable populate when this EDT class calling from somewhere. Done method set the model to jTable.

Comment: search in posts by @MadProgrammer use jtable + swingworker tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JDBCAdapter`, which extends [`AbstractTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), illustrates a typical mapping between relational database and Java data types. It may be seen [here](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/demo/jfc/TableExample/JDBCAdapter.java), and a complete example may be found in `samples/demo/jfc/TableExample`, found among the [*Java SE Development Kit 8u25 Demos and Samples Downloads*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). In outline,

- Override `getColumnClass()`.
- Get the column's data `type` from `ResultSetMetaData`.
- Use `switch(type)` to return the correct [type-token](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html).

Also consider a `SwingWorker<Row, Row>` for finer granularity in `publish()/process()`.

Comment: I must investigate this AbstractTableModel i think. I dont use before. I can follow your links. Thanks for the advices.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a subclass of AbstractTableModel and override the getColumnClass method to set the correct data type for the JTable.

```
public class CustomTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
{
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int index)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public Class<String> getColumnClass(int i)
    {
        //return the Specific class for each column based on index i
    }

}
```