# Is WindowAdapter is an adapter pattern implementation in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns

I was going through design pattern lectures, and I came across the adapter pattern which adapts one interface to another. There, i came across `WindowAdapter`, and I was curious to know how and what implementation `WindowAdapter` uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`WindowAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html) is a good example of the [*class adapter pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern#Class_Adapter_pattern). It provides empty implementations of several interfaces, seen [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.java), as a convenient alternative to doing so repeatedly throughout your code. Complete examples may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8336218/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2061318/230513). In outline,

```
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    });
```

A similar approach is seen in the several other adapters provided in [`java.awt.event`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/package-summary.html).

In contrast, the [*object adapter pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern#Object_Adapter_pattern) "contains an instance of the class it wraps." The class `JDBCAdapter`, examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22183184/230513), is a Swing example
that maps the JDBC interface to the `TableModel` interface."

Comment: But the Window adapter is not matching one interface to another interface, it is providing just an implementation. where as adapter pattern matches one interface to another using some adapter classes

http://www.javatpoint.com/adapter-pattern

Comment: That's the _object adapter pattern_; I've elaborated above.

Comment: To reiterate Rahul's question: the Adapter pattern (both class adapter and object adapter variations of it) involves a target, an adaptee and an adapter. In WindowAdapter, the target is a WindowListener; the adapter is a WindowAdapter; but _where's the adaptee_?

Comment: @k314159: I'm not sure; please ping me if you add a related answer here or pose a new question on this topic.